# $_GET id no me funciona

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente código en php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE categoria_id='{$_GET['id']}'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
//...
```

Que estaré haciendo mal

Answer (score 2):

Si pones lo sgte te funcionaria usando solo php

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE categoria_id='".$_GET["id"]."'";
```

pero ello te traeria problemas de inyeccion de sql,lo podrias hacer de esta manera como lo dice el link
http://blog.aulaformativa.com/como-evitar-una-inyeccion-sql-en-php/

Comment: Esto permite SQL injection, no debe usarse así. Deberías explicar el asunto y proveer alternativas.

Comment: Discula, Si ya me di cuenta, es que pensaba que el solo lo queria hacer funcionar,yo hasta el dia de hoy lo hacia de esa manera, bueno hay que tomar en cuenta la seguridad

Answer (score 2):

Bueno para evitar los temas de inyección porque no haces algo como esto suponiendo que llega un numero claro esta.

```
$categoria_id = (int)$_GET["id"];
if($categoria_id > 0 && is_numeric($categoria_id)){
  $sql =  "SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE categoria_id=".$categoria_id; 
}
```

listo.

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos cuestiones con tu código, uno de seguridad, otro de sintaxis.

Primero permites inyección de código SQL porque no estás validando ni filtrando el GET, y es lo más fácil de abusar ya que solamente tendrían que agregar [?id=''); DROP table users; --](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Te recomiendo uses las funciones `filter_var` o mejor aún: [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php)

```
$filteredId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
// te devuelve el entero si pasa el filtro,
// o false si no lo pasó, entonces puedes
// rechazar la entrada o abortar
if(is_null($filteredId) || $filteredId === FALSE) {
   exit('Dato no valida');
}
// ahora sí, usamos el dato filtrado
```

Ahora con el asunto de sintaxis, para interpolar la variable es correcto si es escalar (no es un array) hacerlo así, como en tu código:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE categoria_id='$filteredId'";
```

Pero si de verdad quieres pasar el miembro de un array, es más sencillo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE categoria_id='$array[id]'";
```

E insistimos: evita a toda costa aceptar variables que pueden manipular los usuarios, sin filtro ni validación.